# Mongoid ignores length validation on embedded document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have the following model:

```
class Man < User

  field :surname,        type: String,  default: ""
  field :name,           type: String,  default: ""

  NAME_LENGTH = 1..50
  validates :surname, length: {in: NAME_LENGTH}, allow_blank: true
  validates :name,    length: {in: NAME_LENGTH}, allow_blank: true
  validates :father,  length: {in: NAME_LENGTH}, allow_blank: true

  field :birthday,       type: Integer #Timestamp

  field :about, type: String

  ABOUT_LENGTH = 2000
  validates :about, length: {maximum: ABOUT_LENGTH}, allow_blank: true

  embeds_many :skills
  MAX_SKILLS_COUNT = 10
  validates :skills, length: {maximum: MAX_SKILLS_COUNT}
  #user got unique skills
  index({login: 1, 'skills.caption_to_index': 1}, {unique: true, sparse: true})

end
```

And embedded skills model:

```
class Skill
  include Mongoid::Document

  CAPTION_LENGTH = 1..50
  CAPTION_FILTER = /[^a-zа-я0-9]/

  field :caption,          type: String
  field :caption_to_index, type: String
  field :order,            type: Integer

  embedded_in :man

  validates :caption, length: {in: CAPTION_LENGTH}
  validates :order,   presence: true

  before_save do |document|
    document.caption_to_index = document.caption.downcase.gsub(CAPTION_FILTER,'')
  end
end
```

The trouble is, mongoid ignores length validation when I do something like this:

```
pry(main)> u = Man.find_by(login:'tester')
pry(main)> s3 = Skill.new(caption:'JavaScript',order:1)
pry(main)> u.skills << s3
```

I can repeat `u.skills << s3` infinite times, and driver saves this to database immidiately.

Another problem is that unique index is not working:

```
index({login: 1, 'skills.caption_to_index': 1}, {unique: true, sparse: true})
```

All indexes were created successfully via `rake:mongoid:create_indexes`

Driver allows to save document with the same caption, here is part of the document in mongo shell as the proof:

```
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("56a0218167e92c3b8b000000"),
                "caption" : "JavaScript",
                "order" : 1,
                "caption_to_index" : "javascript"
        },
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("56a0218167e92c3b8b000000"),
                "caption" : "JavaScript",
                "order" : 1,
                "caption_to_index" : "javascript"
        },
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("56a0218167e92c3b8b000000"),
                "caption" : "JavaScript",
                "order" : 1,
                "caption_to_index" : "javascript"
        },
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("56a0218167e92c3b8b000000"),
                "caption" : "JavaScript",
                "order" : 1,
                "caption_to_index" : "javascript"
        }
```

Test case for uniqueness also fails:

```
require 'rails_helper'
include ApplicationHelper

describe Skill do
  before :each do
    @attrs = attributes_for :tester_man
    @tester = create :tester_man
    expect(@tester).to be_valid
    expect(@tester.persisted?).to be true
  end

  it "skill caption is unique" do
    #debugger
    s1_good = Skill.new(caption:'<<cap Tion ..%#',order:2)
    s2_good = Skill.new(caption:'other_caption',order:4)
    s3_bad  = Skill.new(caption:'CAPTION',order:1)
    expect(s1_good).to be_valid
    expect(s2_good).to be_valid

    @tester.skills = [s1_good,s2_good]
    @tester.save
    expect(@tester).to be_valid

    s3_bad  = Skill.new(caption:'CAPTION',order:1)
    @tester.skills << s3_bad
    expect(@tester).not_to be_valid
  end
end
```

How can I get this code work as expected?